# How to set up alert autoaccept to true/false using AWS device farm for iOS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, appium, aws-device-farm

I defined `capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", false);` This is working on simulator.
However this doesn't work for Device Farm(AWS)'s device.

How can I configure alert autoaccept for ios devices in Device Farm?

If the capabilities are given by Device Farm, how can we override them? Where and how to override the alert autoaccept capability?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Does it work locally and not in Device Farm? Do you have appium server logs? You can overwrite the capabilities sent by the server by the ones sent by the driver object created in the test package.

Comment: also might be helpful https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/11984#issuecomment-453562685

Comment: Yes, it works in local but not in device farm. I added capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", false); which is giving me a chance to handle the pop up options allow/decline depending on the case. Where as in DeviceFarm, it is autoaccepting all the alerts. There are few cases where I need to decline the pop ups. Hence I'm looking to override the autoAccpetAlert to false in Devicefarm. @jmp

Comment: Then you can do that by setting that capability on the driver object. It will override the server args sent by device farm.

Comment: Thanks @jmp overriding the capability worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is - Override the driver capability to false. Default value is true in AWS devicefarm. Overriding  will update it to false. Make sure to look into the appium logs to confirm the actual autoAcceptAlert value being passed. Below is the code which I added to override during the driver instantiation:

capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", false);

#mobileautomation

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass `autoAcceptAlerts: false` explicitly since it is `false` by [default](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/)

Previously AWS device farm was not allowing override Appium capabilities (basically your capabilities were ignored) and in general, most cloud services have a limited number of capabilities you can override.

You need to check Appium server logs in AWS to see how it starts the Appium session:

```
creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.110.0) session

[Appium] Capabilities:
...
[Appium] automationName: XCUITest
[Appium] platformName: iOS
[Appium] autoAcceptAlerts: true
```

And compare it with ones you are providing. If you see the inconsistency, just contact AWS support.

Comment: Correct.. After checking the appium logs, I realized that the autoaccept was passed as true by default.. I had to override it with driver capability and it worked.. Thanks..